# Location Search API for iPhone

Tags: ios, search, location, geonames

I currently have an application that includes a screen where a user can search for a location or place (like Manhattan, Statue of Liberty, Paris, or Golden Gate Bridge) and they get a list of results back. When they select a result, I do some stuff with the lat/long for the result. This is currently using geonames.org, which at times is very unreliable.

My question is simply, is there an alternative to geonames.org that I can either use as primary or fall back on? The API needs to be ok with commercial use, expose a REST style interface, and ideally be free or close to free for commercial use. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

[Google's Geocoding API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/) is close to free, depending on the accessibility of your website. You might be far enough to need a 'Premier' license.

Comment: +1. Google allows for 2,500 requests per day per IP address for free, which should be good enough for almost any app.

Comment: +1 for saying "which should be good enough for"